# Client has disconnected error coming from both development and production environments

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-6.0

The issue occurs when debugging the app also. Front end is angular. Backend is .net core 6.0

I've been trying to fix this for a couple of days and there's very few solutions on the internet. any help will be appreciated

```
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetExceptionHResult=0x80131620Message=The client has disconnectedSource=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISStackTrace:at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IO.AsyncIOOperation.GetResult(Int16 token)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.<ReadBody>d__385.MoveNext()at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.ReadAsync(CancellationToken token)at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.<ReadAsync>d__381.MoveNext()at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter1.GetResult()       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.HttpRequestStream.<ReadAsyncInternal>d__10.MoveNext()       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter1.GetResult()at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.<ReadAsync>d__40.MoveNext()at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.StreamHelperExtensions.<DrainAsync>d__3.MoveNext()at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.NewtonsoftJsonInputFormatter.<ReadRequestBodyAsync>d__12.MoveNext()at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.<BindModelAsync>d__11.MoveNext()at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.<BindModelAsync>d__8.MoveNext()at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0>d.MoveNext()at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0>d.MoveNext()at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1>d.MoveNext()at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1>d.MoveNext()at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0>d.MoveNext()at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.<HandleAsync>d__0.MoveNext()at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()at Camms.Risk.Webapi.Middlewares.ExceptionMiddleware.<InvokeAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\Git\Camms.Risk\Camms.Risk\Camms.Risk.Webapi\Middlewares\ExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 34
```

```
Inner Exception 1:COMException: An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection. (0x800704CD)
```

Could not find a solution. tried making changes on servers also. but nothing seems to be working

Comment: Just a guess here. But since it does have a cancelation token. Could it be from lets say a switch map that sends cancel on you network call that the server does not handle correctly.

Comment: Does not have to be a switchMap specifically, its more if you unsubscribe before a networkcall is returned. Try check you network tab if errors happens when requests are cancelled (in chrome they are they become red lines by default)

Comment: In which execution point you are getting this error? Can you include that relevant scenario where you are getting this very exception? Are you closing your connection before broadcasting? This is exception might thrown when a client disconnects in the middle of uploading a request body. Please share more details.

Comment: It just randomly happens out of no where. My guess is this is a memory leak. This happens even when debugging the app. no console errors. api just breaks with the exception